# "Yet another" thing"s"?

Tags: grammar, expressions

> The global warming causes yet another problem**s**.

I think 'problem**S**' is suitable as this sentence is meant to be followed by a list of problems, not just one problem. However, as far as I know, 'another' cannot lead plural nouns like 'problem**S**'. Are there any alternative expressions of 'yet another' that are grammatically correct and imply the similar concept to 'yet another'?

Comment: ***...causes yet other problems***. *Another* is just the orthographic representation of *an* + *other*.

Comment: More commonly, [*...causes even more problems*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=causes+yet+other+problems%2Ccauses+even+more+problems&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccauses%20even%20more%20problems%3B%2Cc0) Note that the article *(**the** global warming)* is non-idiomatic.

Comment: @StoneyB Then will it be the same meaning if I use "yet **other** problems"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'even more' could be an alternative. Thanks :)

Comment: I would use "still" here. Global warming causes still other problems. Still and yet are rough synonyms.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of ways to express it (still more, even more, yet more, yet other, still other, another set of, etc. etc.). There's little difference if any between most of them. Just trust your instinct that "another" can't be followed by a plural noun, though.